# Stanford Engineering Everywhere CS106B Library

Tags: visual-c++

I  am currently a C# programmer and have been interested in learning more about C++ and data structures.  I found the CS106B class offered free online through the Stanford Engineering Everywhere program which seems like it would be a good fit.

I've tried to install the library files they use for the class and keep getting a message that I have to have visual studio 2005 installed for the setup file to run.  I don't have 2005, but I've tried the express editions of both vc++ 2008 and vc++2005.  Is there any way around this that I can get the proper files installed?

The zip file containing the libraries came with two files, an exe and an msi.

Comment: Could you be more specific about these library files? Are they *.sln files, *.vcproj, *.lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was having the same problem. I found both the .h and the .c files online.

You can find them here:
http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/Roberts/C-library/standard/cslib/

Answer (score 4):

Just got it to work by using some information I found here: http://www.functionx.com/visualc/libraries/staticlib.htm

I'm using Visual C++ 2008 Express. Here's how I did it:

1. Download the PC Starter Code ZIP file for Assignment 1 from the
   current semester's CS106B class website.
   http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/ In that file you'll find a
   folder named "StanfordCPPLib". In that folder, you'll need the
   StanfordCPPLib.lib and the *.h files you want to include.
2. In Visual Studio, create a new project (File -> New -> Project). Select a Win32
   Console Application, choose a name, and click Next.
3. When the Application Wizard pops up, click Next (not Finish). In the
   Application Settings, check the box marked "Empty Project". Click
   Finish.
4. In the Solution Explorer, right click on the Source folder and
   create a new .cpp file. (Add -> New Item -> Code -> C++ File)
5. Find your new project's folder in Windows Explorer. In that folder,
   you should be able to find your new .cpp file you just created.
6. Paste the StanfordCPPLib.lib and your needed *.h files you
   downloaded earlier into the same folder that contains your new .cpp file.
7. Finally, you need to add the library to our new project. In Visual Studio, using
   the main menu, click Project -> Add Existing Item. The dialog should
   default to your project's folder where you just pasted
   StanfordCPPLib.lib. Select StanfordCPPLib.lib and click Add.

You should now be able to add an `#include "example.h"` for whatever .h files you copied into your project folder.

Note: Since you'll be using a newer version of Stanford's custom library, there may be some small differences between the original handouts and the new library. For instance, when using `#include "simpio.h"`, the handouts list a function called `GetLine()`. In the new library, that function is capitalized differently: `getLine()`. Make sure you check the header files for correct syntax/usage.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Dani, with his help, I succeed in installing the library on vs2008(both express and professinal are OK) on win7. With Dani's help,
I have finished the first three assignments in cs106X(winter2010) - life, ADT, boggle - so far.
I'm just a undergraduate in China, thanks so much to the great education of stanford and power of internet.
http://abloggingattempt.blogspot.com/2010/05/stanford-cs106-lib-and-vs2008-express.html

the following are copied mainly from Dani's blog.

Stanford CS106 Lib and VS2008 Express 
The CS106B is a great CS Stanford course available online (iTunes e.g.) in video and for free. All assignments and the course itself use an in-house developed library (not sure if it has a name, cslib, cs106 lib, dunno) available in all of the assignment zips as well as installable with the Xcode/VS2005 wizard installs. The problem - the VS custom wizard will install on VS2005 only (could be that a newer version exists but I couldn't find one). So how to port the VS wizard to VS2008 Express(professional)? 
- I got the 2005 custom wizard setup, PCLibs-VS2005-ADT-Installer.zip and used a small tool , the LessMSIerables(Universal Extractor also works well) in order to extract the contents of the msi file. The msi contains four folders with all the stuff needed to create a new custom wizard. So, the tool extracted the following:

SourceDir 
|- Includes Folder 
|- Library Folder
|- Project Folder
|- Wizard Folder

- Now some copying:

  1. The CS106CPPInc folder inside the 'Includes Folder' goes to 
     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include (as a subfolder!)
  2. 'Library Folder'\CS106CPPLib.lib goes to 
     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib
  3. 'Wizard Folder\AppWiz\CS106 Assignment Wizard' to 
     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\VCWizards\AppWiz 
     (meaning CS106... should appear as a sub-folder of AppWiz)
  4. The three files in 'Project Folder' will go into 
     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\Express\VCProjects\Stanford. One of those three files, the CS106 Assignment Wizard.vsz, needs to be edited (a text file) and its second line should become:

Wizard=VsWizard.VsWizardEngine.9.0

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to go to the CS106B page directly:

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/

And grab newest assignments. They are compatible with VS 2008.

The assignment material from SEE is outdated (VS 2005). The assignments are not discussed in the video, so you won't miss anything by doing that.

Just download from the CS106B page and open in VS 2008, that will work!

Answer (score 0):

Reading through [handout 5P](http://see.stanford.edu/materials/icspacs106b/H05P-UsingVisualStudio.pdf) makes it seem like the installer will expect the file structure VS2005 will create - especially this sentence: "Run (and quit) Visual Studio (you can go ahead and register your copy if it asks you). It is important that you have done this at least once before proceeding to the next step."

Try creating a folder structure like: (under "My Documents") "Visual Studio 2005\Projects" and see if setup.exe will work.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try this when I get home tonight and let you know.

Comment: Didn't work, I'm getting the same message.  Anything else you can think of?

Comment: I tried this with VS 2003 and VS 2008, and it refused to install. I can't think of what else to suggest, other than sending Ms Zelenski an email through the "contact us" link.

Answer (score 0):

I am using visual studio express, and all I did was to just unzip the files it works fine..  [here I have done the CS106B assignment](http://www.codingfriends.com/index.php/2010/06/01/cs106b-assignment-1-life-cycle/) with also the full zip'd up files of that assignment as well, all I did was to uncompress the assignment from the cs106b website and open up the sln (solution) file within visual studio express.

Answer (score 0):

There is no c++ library available for cs106b in unix system. I hope they publish the library in source.