# CS106B Library in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I feel like this question should have been asked already but I haven't been able to find any solutions to accomplish this. But basically I'm going through the youtube lecture videos for Stanford's CS106B course on C++ and I'd like to use their libraries in my Visual Studio 2010, but i'm a VS newbie so I'm not sure how to get the include to work. I've tried to include the path to Project|Options|Include Directories but I get the following error

```
1>------ Build started: Project: HelloWorld, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 1/26/2015 8:28:05 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\HelloWorld.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>HelloWorld.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl getInteger(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?getInteger@@YAHABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0@Z) referenced in function _main
1>C:\CppProjects\HelloWorld\Debug\HelloWorld.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.88
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Update: I downloaded the library from here: http://stanford.edu/~stepp/cppdoc/
And i'm using the Visual Studio IDE.

Any assistance would be awesome, and then I'd know how to include external libraries!

Comment: FYI, "libraries" usually come in at least two pieces.  The first is a header file that contains definitions of the interfaces (how to use the functions) and second is the code for the library functions.  Verify if you need to download both pieces.  Some libraries are headers only.

Comment: Are you using the command line version or the IDE?

Comment: It looks like you forgot to add `simpleio.cpp` to your project. It is part of the library source base. Personally I would build a separate static-library project from their entire source base and link against the resulting lib.

Comment: So I was correct in adding the library to the "Include Directory", but I also need to go and take simpleio.cpp and add it directly to my project? The #include isn't enough?

Comment: It isn't enough. Were it a template library it *may* have been, but not in this case. As I said. I would build their library as a separate project file (part of the same workspace, which you'll be adding to throughout the term). Its a little more complicated, but you don't have to play "where's their function implementation?" again for the remainder of the semester, as they will all be in a single lib you're linking to your exe project.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "build their library as a separate project file". Should I add all of their header files to the Header Files folder and all the .cpp files to the Source Files of the project thats open if I want to use their libraries?

Comment: [Stanford Engineering Everywhere CS106B Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012119/stanford-engineering-everywhere-cs106b-library) has some information about using Visual Studio 2008 with the StanfordCPPLib source.