# Adding Stanford C++ Library to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am learning C++ through 'Programming Abstractions in C++' by Eric S. Roberts, which covers the content of Stanford CS106B. It requires to use the Stanford C++ Library to work on a lot of the examples given in the book.

I am however using Visual Studio Community 2015 and am pretty much unable to link the Stanford C++ Library to it. I have tried everything that I found so far on the internet. Perhaps the library is not compatible with VS 2015 yet?

Would you please, help me with a set of instructions. I am not a software engineer or a CS. I am an ME, so any detailed instructions would be very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Please post any output you are getting.

Comment: it looks like the Stanford library is intended to be used with gcc rather than Visual Studio. It sounds like you are doing this on your own and not as part of a standard class. I suggest that you find a different resource to learn C++ so that you can learn C++11 and later with the improvements that have come with the new standards.

Comment: Thanks. That is true. I am doing it on my own and it would be nice to use another resource too. But I am taking another class at Stanford this winter and CS106B is one of the pre-requisites so I would like to stay close to it in content.

Comment: [Stanford Engineering Everywhere CS106B Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012119/stanford-engineering-everywhere-cs106b-library) has some information about using Visual Studio 2008 with the StanfordCPPLib source. If that helps you, please up vote the question and the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked for the Stanford C++ library and found that is contains **pure** **header and source files**.

So what you could do is:

**A)** Just add the files directly to your project.(Drag-n-drop)

**B)** Create a new **static library project** with Stanford library files, **compile** it  and then **link** it to your personal project.

Stanford library source code:

http://stanford.edu/~stepp/cppdoc/

https://github.com/stepp/stanford-cpp-library/tree/master/StanfordCPPLib

Comment: I would vote for the new static library project. I just tried using the zip file of the source from stanford.edu and it looks like there are some compiler problems with Visual Studio 2013 possibly due to the last changes to the library using an older version of Visual Studio.