# Using Stanford CS106B C++ libraries with Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libraries

I am a newbie and have been trying to make the Stanford C++ libraries work with Visual Studio Community 2015.  I have looked up very many places and been tyring to follow very many instructions, the most useful of them I have found to be the 7 step instructions on this page:

[Stanford Engineering Everywhere CS106B Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012119/stanford-engineering-everywhere-cs106b-library)

However, after following all the instructions, and while trying to build an empty project, I get the following errors:LNK2019 and LNK1120.

Of course, If I run a very simple snippet of code, I get tens of LNK2019s (and one LNK1120).
I have been trying to fix this endless hours but to no avail.  Help will me much appreciated.

Comment: Is that library already built and you are just trying to use it?  If so, it has to be compiled with the same version of Visual Studio and with the same memory model.

Comment: There is a StanfordCPPLib.Lib file that I included in the project directory, and then 'Added' it as an 'Existing Item', which provided it to the project under the Source Files.  I guess that means that the library already built?  If not, can I rebuild it myself?

Comment: That means the library is already built.  You will have to make sure it is built with the same compiler that is used with VS 2015 and it is using the same runtime libraries (e.g. /MD, /MT, etc).  If not, you could build it yourself if you have the source files.

Comment: I see.  The source files are available and I have already tried to do it once using the instructions here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx

I ran into problems and many errors doing that as well.  But according to what you say, at least now I know I was on the right track.  Just to clarify, I need to build a static library, is that right?

Comment: I retried building the library using with the help of the instructions on the above msdn page.  In particular, I created an empty Static Library Project, and then added all the header and source files to it (right click on project -> Add Existing Item).  When I try to build the project, I get a ton of C1083 errors, for example:  
"Cannot open include file: 'console.h': No such file or directory."   That is while both console.h and console.cpp are included in the Header Files and Source Files, respectively.

Comment: You have to tell it where to find the headers.  It's on one of the properties pages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95877/discussion-between-kambiz-and-anon-mail).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Stanford C++ Library to Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239146/adding-stanford-c-library-to-visual-studio-2015)